# Use Residues to find the inverse Laplace transform $F(s)=\frac{2s^3}{(s^2-4)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse, laplace-transform, residue-calculus, inverse-laplace

> Use Residues to find the inverse Laplace transform $F(s)=\frac{2s^3}{(s^2-4)}$.

The answer from the text book is $f(t)=\cosh^2(t)+\cos^2(t)$.

But my result is $2\cos^2(t)\cdot \cosh^2(t)$. Which is correct?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your $F(s)$ is not a Laplace transform of a regular function.

Comment: Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). ("MathJacky uses MathJax" - sounds good!)

Comment: Welcome. Posting image is discouraged. [Images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13677/963109) may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Since you are new contributor, the images have been converted to text for once (If you can't see text, assume that conversion process is in Queue). It is advisable to get yourself trained with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that from future you can type your question self.  Happy Learning!

Answer (score 4):

The Laplace of $\cos^2(t)$ can be derived from the famous half angle formula. What you get is
$$\mathcal{L}\{\cos^2(t)\}(s) = \frac{1}{2s} + \frac{s}{2(s^2+4)}$$
On the other hand, Laplace of $\cosh^2(t)$ is found by employing its definition in terms of exponentials. In this case, you get
$$\mathcal{L}\{\cosh^2(t)\}(s) = \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{s-2} + \frac{1}{2s} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{s+2}$$
So the Laplace of the book's answer is
$$F_{\mathrm{book}}(s) = \frac{1}{s} + \frac{s}{2(s^2+4)} + \frac{1}{4} [\frac{1}{s-2} + \frac{1}{s+2}]$$
By Mathematica, put this all together to see that the function with the inverse laplace of the book's answer is
$$F_{\mathrm{book}}(s) = \frac{2s^4-16}{s(s^4-16)}$$
This is simply not equal to the Laplace transform you stated. By computer algebra, the answer you gave does not equal the desired Laplace transform either.

**Neither seems correct.** So let's work through it from the beginning.

Note (by long division and then a little partial fractions) $$\frac{2s^3}{s^2-4} = 2s + \frac{4}{s-2} + \frac{4}{s+2}$$
Integrating over a Bromwich contour with real part greater than 2, we need consider the inegral
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i } \int_{B} [2s + \frac{4}{s-2} + \frac{4}{s+2}] e^{st} ds$$
For a moment ignore the first term in the integrand. You are then left with a simple pole at both $s=2$ and $s=-2$. Hence the inverse transform gives
$$f(t) \approx 4e^{-2t} + 4e^{2t} = 8(\frac{e^{-2t} + e^{2t}}{2}) = 8\cosh(2t)$$
The integral from the first term is
$$2 \frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{B} s e^{st} ds$$
You can recognize this as the derivative of the dirac delta function in its Fourier-type expression. Hence a full answer is
$$f(t) = 2 \delta'(t) + 8\cosh(2t)$$
But if you assume $t \geq 0$, that first term in the integrand is holomorphic over the contour and hence disappears giving the answer with only the hyperbolic function.

Hope this helps.